# Rotate sprite using touch data

Tags: ios, objective-c, trigonometry

So I have a sprite-node and I want to rotate it by tracking the touch of the user...
This is what I did:

```
- (void)calculateAngleAndRotateSelectedCellForThouchPoint:(CGPoint)tPoint withDuration:(NSTimeInterval) duration
{
    CGPoint cellPoint = self.currentlySelectedCell.position;
    // math here
    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(tPoint, previousTouchPoint)) {
        float rotationAngle = radiansFromSlope(slopeDifference(cellPoint, tPoint, cellPoint, previousTouchPoint));
        SKAction *rotateForAimingAction = [SKAction rotateByAngle:rotationAngle duration:duration];
        [self.currentlySelectedPlayer runAction:rotateForAimingAction];
    }
}

    #pragma mark - Trigonometric calculations ( C functions)

    static inline float slopeBetweenPoints(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2)
    {
        return ((p2.y-p1.y) / (p2.x-p1.x));
    }

    static inline float slopeDifference(CGPoint pl1_1, CGPoint pl1_2, CGPoint pl2_1, CGPoint pl2_2)
    {
        return (slopeBetweenPoints(pl1_1, pl1_2) - slopeBetweenPoints(pl2_1, pl2_2));
    }

    static inline float radiansFromSlope(float slope)
    {
        return atanf(slope);
    }

    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        touchStartTime = event.timestamp;
        crtIntervalPrev = event.timestamp;
    }

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        NSTimeInterval crtThouchDuration = event.timestamp - touchStartTime;

        if (crtThouchDuration > TAP_TIMEOUT) {
            /// rotate the selected player sprite
            currentTouchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
            NSTimeInterval time_delta = event.timestamp - crtIntervalPrev;
            [self calculateAngleAndRotateSelectedCellForThouchPoint:currentTouchPoint withDuration:time_delta];
            crtIntervalPrev = event.timestamp;
        }
        }

        - (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
        {
            [self resetTouchTimes];
            [self resetTouchPoints];
            [self deselectAllCells];
        }

        - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
        {
            touchEndTime = event.timestamp;
            NSTimeInterval touchDuration = touchEndTime - touchStartTime;

            if (touchDuration < TAP_TIMEOUT) {
                // it's a tap ... so deselect the selected cell
                [self deselectAllCells];
            }
            [self resetTouchPoints];
            [self resetTouchTimes];
         }
```

This is rotating, but WAY too fast... any clues why?

Comment: Sorry for off-topic but you can have a division by 0 problem in `slopeBetweenPoints(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2)` when `p2.x == p1.x`.

Comment: did you try by increase the duration, say 2*duration

Comment: It's great to do things like this for polishing up your math skills, but... Any reason you're not using [`UIRotationGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIRotateGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIRotationGestureRecognizer)?

Comment: cause i need both tap gesture and rotation gesture and tap on sprite is handled inside it's own subclass... i don't think gesture recognizers work very well with that, also isn't rotation gesture only with 2 fingers, I need only a 1 finger gesture... and it isn't the scene view that will rotate...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the `calculateAngleAndRotateSelectedCellForThouchPoint` method.
Instead of running the action, just assign the rotation angle.

```
- (void)calculateAngleAndRotateSelectedCellForThouchPoint:(CGPoint)tPoint withDuration:(NSTimeInterval) duration
{
    CGPoint cellPoint = self.currentlySelectedCell.position;
    // math here
    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(tPoint, previousTouchPoint)) {
        float rotationAngle = radiansFromSlope(slopeDifference(cellPoint, tPoint, cellPoint, previousTouchPoint));

        self.currentlySelectedPlayer.zRotation = rotationAngle;
    }
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work quite ok, but it's a lot better. I get a jump in rotation at a certain point... might be that division by zero somebody noticed

Answer (score 0):

Based on some answer that I found around here (in the side bar of this question)
The solution:

```
- (void)calculateAngleAndRotateSelectedCellForThouchPoint:(CGPoint)tPoint
{
    CGPoint cellPoint = self.currentlySelectedCell.position;
    // math here
    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(tPoint, previousTouchPoint)) {

        float dy = cellPoint.y - tPoint.y;
        float dx = cellPoint.x - tPoint.x;

          self.currentlySelectedCell.zRotation = - (atan2(dy,dx) - DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90));
    }
}
```

That was simpler than I expected.